# Flutter why do I get an appBar even though i didn't put any appBar command in my scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

Is there a way to modify the appbar that I get from `pushedName` or is there a way that I can remove the appbar? I've been searching for around 2 hours already and I can't find any answer relate of it. Some of question suggest to use the appBar command. Tried it already but for me they give me more appbar now. and they become double after I putting the appbar in my scaffold widget. This is the pic of the app bar now. (I even can't change my icon color in that app bar)

```
class _seller_profile_screenState extends State<seller_profile_screen> {
  double tp = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
              parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                  pinned: true,
                  stretch: true,
                  expandedHeight: 200,
                  flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, cons) {
                    tp = cons.biggest.height;
                    return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      centerTitle: true,
                      background: Stack(
                        fit: StackFit.expand,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/cloud_background.jpg',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          SafeArea(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Column(children: [
                                // 
                              ]),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code that you have so the scenario can be reproduce by us...

Comment: @WilsonToribio there you go. thanks for remind me of it

Comment: If you do not want to have an AppBar then do not put a SliverAppBar in your CustomScrollView.

Comment: `SliverAppBar` is `AppBar` just used inside the slivers and you have it in your code. Remove it.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by `pushedName`.

Comment: @TheUltimateOptimist ahhh i didnt think of it. but is there a way to make a custom sliverappbar design?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to screen hierarchy. There was one screen before this so you get back button by default when you use snackbar. If you want to remove this then do like this:

```
Scaffold(
 appBar:AppBar(
   ...
   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  ),
 body:...);
```